# WCF Library in IIS Hosting not connecting from client

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Hello I have a WCF service library project and I have created a WPF app to host it for testing and that works just fine, but I also created a web app to host it in IIS for production and when I try to connect to the IIs one I never can.

I am using a net.tcp bininding and I have gone in to IIS and added the net.tcp biniding to the web app and the web site.

Basically this is a duplex service with the methods marked as one way. When I call the method in the client the callback never gets called and I end up just sitting there waiting for several minutes before I close the application. When I self host the service I get a response almost immediately on the callback.

Also I have tried using localhost:808 and just localhost. If I use svcutil to generate the config it leaves the port off of the address. I don't get any errors that I am aware of, but I honestly don't really know how to tell if I get any errors it throws from IIS.

Also if I go to `http://localhost:9595/EcuWebService/Service.svc` I get the page that tells me to use svcutil to generate my client proxy.

As Jocke suggested below I attached a debugger and received this error: The service '/EcuWebService/service' does not exist.

Also here is the contents of my svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="EcuWeb.ServiceLib.Contracts.EcuWebServiceMain" %>
```

below is my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
  <appSettings>
     <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 </system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
        <service name="EcuWeb.ServiceLib.Contracts.EcuWebServiceMain">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:808/EcuWebService/service" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint" contract="EcuWeb.ServiceLib.Contracts.IEcuWebServiceMain">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:808/EcuWebService/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
               <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http://localhost/EcuWebService" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is the config for the client app. The commented out endpoint is the endpoint that I use when not hosting in IIS and it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
     <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file    must be added to the host's 
          app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
     <system.serviceModel>
       <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint" />
        </netTcpBinding>
       </bindings>
     <client>
      <!--<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5555/EcuWebService/service"
       binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint"
       contract="EcuWebService.IEcuWebServiceMain" name="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint">
        <identity>
         <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
       </endpoint>-->
         <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/EcuWebService/service"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint"
            contract="EcuWebService.IEcuWebServiceMain"    name="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
</client>
<services>
  <service name="Ecu.Service.Contracts.EcuServiceMain">
    <endpoint address="service" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="netNamedPipe_EcuClientEndpoint" contract="Ecu.Service.Contracts.IEcuServiceMain">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="mexNamedPipe_EcuClientEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/EcuServiceClient" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="">
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally got this figured out.

First I had to add:

```
<host>
 <baseAddresses>
  <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5555/EcuWebService" />
  <add baseAddress="http://localhost/EcuWebService" />
 </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Then for the endpoint I just used:

```
<service name="EcuWeb.ServiceLib.Contracts.EcuWebServiceMain">
<endpoint address="service" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
 name="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint" contract="EcuWeb.ServiceLib.Contracts.IEcuWebServiceMain">
 <identity>
  <dns value="localhost" />
 </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Then in the client I had to use:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/EcuWebService/Service.svc/service"
    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint"
    contract="EcuWebService.IEcuWebServiceMain" name="netTcp_EcuWebServiceEndpoint">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
```

When I added the port it didn't work, but once I removed it it worked no problem. Also I doubt the base address is required as IIS is giving the address anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What happens? Do you get an exception? Can you browse it in the IIS?

Your service has:

```
endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:808/EcuWebService/mex"
```

and the client:

```
endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/EcuWebService/service"
```

I think you need provide more details to get a good answer.

Comment: I added more info, but I don't get any error in the client and yes I can browse to the http address in a browser without any problems, but I don't have any http endpoints defined for communication.

Comment: Try to enable debugging in the IIS/WAS and see if you can get some more information, have you looked in the event log on the machine?

Comment: Ok I attached a debugger and got The service '/EcuWebService/service' does not exist.